# How to disable or hide Github's link "Create branch:" under the list of branches?

Tags: github, branch

In the Code page of GitHub, at the top, above the file view, there is a scrolling menu to access the list of branches. And it includes a searching field.

When you do a research, there is automatically an additional entry that offers to Create a branch with the name of your research.

[image]

It's ok to have the branch creation in the dedicated page of branches. But at this spot, no, for me, it's prone to accident.

**How to remove this additional entry, or just disable it there?**

Comment: I don't believe there's such an option.